# How can I make my application prompt a "Would like to send you notifications" message when first opened?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just downloaded an application (not mine) for my studies and noticed that the first time it's opened that a message saying it would like to send me notifications appears. Can anyone explain how to code this to happen with a Forms application?  Below is a screen print to show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: It seems already you done it for iOS.

Comment: This isn't my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Timo's answer isn't wrong but few subtle thing are there which should be noticed.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    //Register your app for remote notifications.
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
    {
        //iOS 10 or later
        var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
            Console.WriteLine(granted);
        });

        //For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;
        //Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this; //FCM
    }
    else
    {
        //iOS 9 or before
        var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
    }
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
    //App.Configure(); If using firebase
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you confirm this should be added to the AppDelegate class?  Also not part of the question, but for interest what's the purpose of the //App.Configure that you commented out. What's that about firebase.  thanks

Comment: @Alan2 - This should be added in `AppDelegate`s `FinishedLaunching` method. If you are using firebase than you need to have that line to configure or initialize firebase in your application.

Answer (score 1):

On iOS, you need to use the [UNUserNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter) to request the authorization by modifying the AppDelegate class:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    // Ask for the permission to send notifications
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization (UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert, (approved, err) => {
        // User approved
    });

    return true;
}
```

On Android, you don't have to ask for push notification permission separately and no changes are required in your code as long as you have the INTERNET permission set up.